# Concatenating macro name before expansion

Tags: c, macros, concatenation

Let's say I have two macro definitions:

```
#define TEST 0
#define TEST_NAME "Joe"
```

I'd like to create a macro that can get access to the second definition from the first.

I tried the following

```
#define ID_TO_NAME(id) id ## _NAME
printf("%s\n", ID_TO_NAME(TEST));
```

However this doesn't work because the result is 0_NAME instead of TEST_NAME. Is there a way to concatenate the tokens before the macro expansion occurs?

Comment: Which preprocessor are you using ?

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/VbQkUZ In your question, please use *the exact code* which fails for you; otherwise, it is difficult or impossible to guess what the problem might be. (In this case, my guess is that you are nesting macro calls.) [ask] / [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be reduced to (in order to understand what happened only):

```
#define TEST 0
#define TEST_NAME "Joe"
#define ID_TO_NAME(id) id ## _NAME
ID_TO_NAME(TEST)
```

`##` is the concatenation operator in  Preprocessor which paste 2 tokens to form another **valid** token. The problem is one of the tokens is an argument parameter.

***[From GNU C Preprocessor documentation (3.5):](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html)***

> **If either of the tokens next to an ‘##’ is a parameter name**, **it is
>   replaced by its actual argument before ‘##’ executes**. As with
>   stringification, **the actual argument is not macro-expanded first**. If
>   the argument is empty, that ‘##’ has no effect.

What happens to `ID_TO_NAME(TEST)`? :

1. So first it will be generated to `TEST_NAME` creating a valid token.
2. After that the CPP will do a macro expansion to `TEST_NAME` which becomes `"joe"`.

So the normal result would be `"joe"` **based on the input of your question**.

In your case you said it was `0_NAME` the only reason would be:

- There was an expansion of argument `TEST` before being concatenated which requires some definitions of macros and which you did not mention.

Or

- There was a redefinition of an object-like macro `TEST_NAME` to `0_NAME` before the invocation.

What I suggest is: check your code again or reformulate your question.